# Google Dataproc Hive instance through a third party tool

Tags: hadoop, hive, google-cloud-dataproc

Need your help here. I hope to connect my Google Dataproc Hadoop/Hive instance with a third party tool and started with "Toad for Hadoop". Is it a good choice ? Or is there any other tool i could use ?

Answer (score 1):

Dataproc runs a HiveServer2 server by default, and if you set up your firewall rules in Compute Engine appropriately (don't just open it up to all incoming connections from the outside internet! Limit it to your own IP addresses from which you're connecting), any third_party tools can connect just fine.

You can find the external IP address of your master hostname through the cloud console GUI. See `/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml` on the master node to see Hive's various configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of HiveServer2 gets deployed as part of default Google Data Proc cluster. ( Mostly not).

Third Party tools needs JDBC connection to connect to Hive over network. Hence I doubt if this can be achieved.

Only way to access Hive is using command prompt.

1. SSH to Master Node
2. Type `hive`
3. You should see `hive>` prompt.

Apart from Toad for Hadoop, you can also try SQL Workbench but only pain is to add required jars manually. Except the footprint Toad for Hadoop is good tool though.